# Expectation with Dirac measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, dirac-delta

Let $\mathbf{P}_X [A] := \frac{1}{2} \delta_0 (A) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{A \cap (0, \infty)} e^{-t} dt$ for $A \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R})$. What is $\mathbf{E} [X]$?

I tried finding the density and computed $\mathbf{E} [X]$ as follows:

$F_X (x) = \mathbf{P} [X \le x] = \mathbf{P}_X [(-\infty, x]] = \tfrac{1}{2} \delta_0 ((-\infty, x]) + \frac{1}{2} (1 - e^{-x}) \mathbf{1}_{(0, \infty)} (x)$;

$f_X (x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} e^{-x}, & x > 0; \\0, & \text{else}.\end{cases}$

Hence, $\mathbf{E} [X] = \int_0^\infty x \cdot \frac{1}{2} e^{-x} d x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Is this solution correct? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Technically there is no PDF because the Dirac measure part isn't absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, but that doesn't wind up affecting the expectation because the Dirac measure is at 0 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without resorting to densities (which as pointed out aren't entirely rigorous in this case since $P(X=0)=1/2$) you can use the fact that your random variable is non-negative and hence
$$
EX=\int_0^\infty 1-F(x)\, dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{2}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found a proof of the shortcut at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach gives the right answer but isn't rigorous because the distribution doesn't have a true probability density function.

A way to make your argument rigorous is to prove the following result: Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures and that $f$ is both $\mu$ and $\nu$ integrable. Prove that $\pi(A) := \mu(A) + \nu(A)$ is a measure, $f$ is $\pi$-integrable, and
$$ \int f(x) \ \pi(\text{d}x) = \int f(x)\ \mu(\text{d}x) + \int f(x)\ \nu(\text{d}x) .$$
This is a rather intuitive result, the easiest way I can think of to prove it is to use the monotone class theorem for functions. Then just exploit that $P_X(A) = \frac{1}{2} \delta_0(A) + \frac{1}{2} \mu(A)$ where $\mu$ is the measure corresponding to the exponential distribution.